# Why are d3's select() and selectAll() behaving differently here?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing around with the [drag multiples example](http://bl.ocks.org/1557377), and I noticed something I can't explain.

In this snippet:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
    .data(d3.range(16).map(function() { return {x: width / 2, y: height / 2}; }))
    .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

I changed `selectAll` to `select`.  It still works, but now the `svg` elements are added *after* the `</body>` tag.  The original code, with `selectAll`, adds them after the `<body>` tag as you would expect.

Since the original html contains no hardcoded `<svg>` element, I would think that both `select` and `selectAll` just return the empty selection.  So I cannot figure out why they result in different behavior.

I'm just looking for an explanation.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it does not make sense to select *one* element if you actually want to deal with multiple ones. So I think using `.select` + `.data` should not be a valid use case anyway. `.select` seems to create a selection with `parentNode` being `<html>` (the HTML root node) and `.selectAll` a selection with `<body>` (after `.select('body')`). Appending the elements to `html` does not seem to be the expected behaviour, but it could be intentional. I'd ask the author, it could be a bug as well.

Comment: re: your point about the validity of the use-case of select, my understanding was that both select and selectAll return a selection object, which is a kind of collection.  it just so happens that the collection returned by select happens to have a single element (or is empty).  so applying data() is valid in both cases.  please correct me if that understanding is wrong

Comment: .select should just grab the first element that matches the identifier, it shouldn't append differently than selectAll. I'd post it as a bug on Github.

Answer (score 10):

The basic difference between select and selectAll is that select squashes the hierarchy of the existing selections, while selectAll preserves it.

Therefore, when you use one selectAll after the other, the result will be a lot like a list of nested for loops.

http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/

Answer (score 6):

Check Mike Bostock's post about select/selectAll: [Nested Selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)

To quote:

> There is an important difference between select and selectAll: select preserves the existing   grouping, whereas selectAll creates a new grouping. Calling select thus preserves the data, index and even the parent node of the original selection!

Answer (score 3):

Other answers here are a bit off, and don't cite the correct source; this is only tangentially related to nesting. D3's author explains it in his [join](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) concept. I review that here for completeness:

You have two sets (arrays):

1. the dataset that drives the visualisation;
2. the HTML elements that represent each data item in that dataset.

These sets *may not be exactly the same* at any given time during the application's run. So we do a little management to ensure they do match, at all times (every processing frame). Imagine a real-time data set (stream) - maybe last time we only got 98 elements, now instead we've got 100. The page still has 98 `<div>`s, but now we need to create 2 more. That's *exactly* what happens, automagically, in your code:

1. By calling `.selectAll("svg")` you are saying, "Create a set of `<svg>` elements *even if they don't exist*." Another way to put this is, "Let's imagine we can select a set of `<svg>`s that matches the dataset we've given. Now, go ahead and create that set."
2. ...Which is exactly what `.enter().append(...)` then does. Conversely, if there had been too many elements for our new dataset (because we previously had more in elements in the dataset than we do now), `.exit().remove(...)` would deal with that.

`enter` is the set of elements we need to create; `exit` is those we need to remove.

Your `.selectAll("svg")` would return nothing, but as it is more of a proposal than an imperative, it then creates what it needs in `.enter().append("svg")`, in order to match the dataset given.